# Is it possible we have a great validation accuracy and both low sensitivity and specificity in balanced validation set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a problem. I'm using Keras with TensorFlow backend to image recognition. There are two classes: positive and negative tasks.

I'm using a pretrained model (with freeze weights) with a dense layers (that is not freeze).

I have reported a problem: training after 100 epochs, I got that results bellow:

> Epoch 98/100 488/488 [==============================] - 222s
>   454ms/step - loss: 0.0774 - acc: 0.9720 - sensitivity: 0.9746 -
>   specificity: 0.9683 - val_loss: 0.0660 - val_acc: 0.9697 -
>   val_sensitivity: 0.4412 - val_specificity: 0.5368
>  Epoch 99/100
>   488/488 [==============================] - 221s 453ms/step - loss:
>   0.0791 - acc: 0.9687 - sensitivity: 0.9729 - specificity: 0.9647 - val_loss: 0.0930 - val_acc: 0.9570 - val_sensitivity: 0.5428 -
>   val_specificity: 0.4245
>  Epoch 100/100 488/488
>   [==============================] - 221s 453ms/step - loss: 0.0775 -
>   acc: 0.9693 - sensitivity: 0.9715 - specificity: 0.9655 - val_loss:
>   0.0751 - val_acc: 0.9684 - val_sensitivity: 0.4482 - val_specificity: 0.5285

I got an accuracy of 96%, loss of 0.0751 (binary cross entropy) and low both sensitivity and specificity. It could be a problem with the class imbalance, but I have 2600 test instances, which positive class has 1302 and negative class has 1298.

If we have an accuracy of +90% it was expected that one of the two another metrics could provide a good result classification. If these metrics are for evaluate the hit of each class, and we have a high accuracy, how can we get low values for **both** metrics?

I have no idea what is happening here, someone can help me?

There are my sensitivity and specificity functions bellow:

```
def sensitivity(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    return true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
def specificity(y_true, y_pred):
    true_negatives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip((1-y_true) * (1-y_pred), 0, 1)))
    possible_negatives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(1-y_true, 0, 1)))
    return true_negatives / (possible_negatives + K.epsilon())
```

I apologize for my bad English. Thank you for your help!

I tried to make a binary classification with images. I used transfer learning, and added two metrics for evaluation of the model: sensitivity and specificity.

If we have a great accuracy in a binary classification task with **balanced** validation data, we expect get great results in the validation sensitivity OR specificity. There is some inconsistency in the model or metric evaluation.

**EDIT 9/9**
I have tried to use another transfer learning OR simple models and I've got the same results. I really don't understand what is this.

> Epoch 100/100 488/488 [==============================] - 217s 445ms/step - loss: 0.0575 - acc: 0.9767 - sensitivity: 0.9793 - specificity: 0.9737 - val_loss: 0.0731 - val_acc: 0.9653 - val_sensitivity: 0.4904 - val_specificity: 0.4852

Comment: Your premise that if we have high accuracy we should also have high sensitivity & specificity is wrong.

Comment: Hi, desert. Thanks for your response! I think I explained wrong. If we have an accuracy of +90% it was expected that one of the two another metrics could provide a good result classification. If these metrics are for evaluate the hit of each class, and we have a high accuracy, how can It have make low value in the both metrics?

Comment: My idea is: if we have an so high accuracy, it was expected at least we receive an high acceptance in one of classes, but it doesn't happen.

About my metrics, I got these in this link (I had no idea how to implement this in the Keras): [link](http://www.deepideas.net/unbalanced-classes-machine-learning/)

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: I checked the functions and they are correct; given that, this is not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (minus the programming details).